# $x+2$ is irreducible in the power series ring $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$

Tags: ring-theory, power-series

For the last few days I am trying to prove that $x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$. I think that it is false...  I would be very much thankful for any kind of suggestions and help.

Comment: Why do you think it is false?

Answer (score 12):

Recall that the invertible elements are those where the constant coefficient is invertible in the integers, so the constant coefficient is $\pm 1$. (Your element is thus certainly not invertible; though we do not really needs this.)

Assume a factorization $(x+2) = f g$. Let us write $f= a_0 + Xf_1$ and $g= b_0 + X g_1$ with integers $a_0,b_0$ and powerseries $f_1, g_1$. So $2 = a_0 b_0$. Thus $a_0$ or $b_0$ is $\pm 1$ and again by the above claim you now get that the element is irreducible since one of the factors is invertible.

Comment: Is it really obvious that the factorization is a prori made up of two degree $1$ polynomials? We are considering power series. But anyways: In any factorization the product of the constant terms of the factors is $2$, hence one of them is a unit.

Comment: @MooS no it is not, and I did not mean to imply that. $f_1,g_1$ should be powerseries, which is why I denote them with the same letter as the orginal powerseries as opposed to the same letter as the constant coefficient. I admit I could have been more clear though. Let me edit it.

Comment: I feel like you've switched the words "invertible" and "irreducible."

Comment: @anorton I recall a characterization  of the *invertible* elements (or units) to be able to assert that every factorization of $2+X$ has at least one factor being invertible, which means the element is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic of power series rings $R[[X]]$ where $R$ is an integral domain is very simple. The formula $(1-aX)^{-1}=\sum_{i\in\Bbb N}a^iX^i$ (where $a$ is any power series) shows that any series with constant term$~1$, and therefore any series with invertible (in$~R$) constant term is invertible. This means that the map $R[[X]]\to R$ that selects the constant coefficient not only maps invertible elements to invertible elements (as any unitary ring morphism does) but also maps non-invertible elements to non-invertible elements. This means that any element that maps to a nonzero element $r\in R$ has the same invertible/irreducible/reducible status as $r$. You element $x+2$ maps to the prime $2$, so it is irreducible.

The only irreducibles not covered by this are those that map to$~0$. But it is not hard to see there is only one class of these namely the one of $X$: the power series that start with $X$ with an invertible coefficient.

Comment: I don't see why the constant coefficient map should preserve irreducible/reducible status. For example, $4 + X$ should be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$, though its constant coefficient is reducible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\ h(c_0 + c_1 x+\cdots) = c_0.\ $ Apply the following consequence of unit-faithful homs

**Lemma** $\,\ $ If $\,h\,$ is a monoid hom such that $h(x)$ unit $\,\color{#0a0}\Rightarrow\, x\,$ unit then $\,\color{#c00}{h(a)\,\ \rm irred}$ $\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ irred

**Proof** $\,\ a = bc\,\Rightarrow\, ha = hb\ hc\,\color{#c00}{\Rightarrow} hb\,$ unit or $\,hc\,$ unit $\color{#0a0}\Rightarrow\, b\,$ unit or $\,c\,$ unit $\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ irred

Comment: But you missed the irreducibles that map to $0$.

Comment: @Marc It was not "missed" but, rather, omitted since it plays no role in the OP (and, as you noted, it is trivial to resolve if need be). By giving an answer that fills in all the details of the above hint there is now little left for the OP to discover on their own.