# Why is $\frac{1}{x+2} = \sum_k^\infty (-1)^k(1+x)^k \in \mathbb{Z} [[x]]$ not the inverse of $x+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As also stated in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164830/x2-is-irreducible-in-the-power-series-ring-mathbbzx), a formal power series is a unit in $R[[x]]$ iff it is constant coefficient is a unit in the ring $R$. However, for example, we can find the inverse of $1+x$ by observing that $\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_k^\infty (-x)^k$, so to find the inverse of $x+2$, I simply observed that 
$$\frac{1}{x+2} = \frac{1}{1- (-1-x) } = \sum_k^\infty (-1)^k(1+x)^k  \in \mathbb{Z} [[x]].$$

However, this contradicts with the stated theorem that since $2$ is not unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, $x+2$ is a non unit, so what is wrong in my argument ?

Comment: Why do you assert that complicated sum is an element of $\Bbb Z[[x]]$?

Comment: Let $|\sum_{n=N}^{N+m} a_n x^n| = 2^{-N}$ for $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}, a_N\ne 0$. It is a non-archimedian absolute value on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[[x]],|.|$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Z}[x],|.|$. The sequence $\sum_{k=0}^K (-1)^k (1+x)^k$ is not Cauchy in $\mathbb{Z}[x],|.|$ so it diverges. Replacing $|.|$ by $|\sum_{n=N}^{N+m} a_n (1+x)^n|_2 = 2^{-N}$ then $\sum_{k=0}^K (-1)^k (1+x)^k$ is Cauchy and its limit belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[[1+x]],|.|_2$

Comment: @reuns Thanks your explanation, but I just took first year graduate course on Algebra, and I don't know what do you mean by "completion" of a polynomial ring. In fact, I just did a quick research, but I think that beyond what I know allows.

Comment: @onurcanbektas $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to its usual absolute value : adding to the space the limits of Cauchy sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space An absolute value is a metric compatible with the addition and the multiplication which guaranties those extend to the completed metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
$$\sum_k(-1)^k(1+x)^k=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k + \sum_{k \geq 0}\sum_{1\leq r\leq k}{k\choose r}x^r$$
is not convergent in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

Comment: What do you mean by convergent in this setup ? Isn't each coefficient of $x^r$ an integer ?

Comment: What is the constant term? What is the coefficient of $x^k$? The sum is nonsense. @onurcanbektas

Comment: "What is the constant term ?": a good question :). Thanks for you answer.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(1+x)^k \in \mathbb{Z}[[1+x]]$ @DavidHill

Comment: @reuns What is your point? The problem regards finding inverses *in* $\mathbb{Z}[[x]].

Comment: Just that this is about the difference between $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[[1+x]]$

Answer (score 6):

Not that $ \sum_k^\infty (-1)^k(1+x)^k$ is not an element of $ \mathbb{Z} [[x]]$. For example  the constant term of $\sum_k^\infty (-1)^k(1+x)^k $ is not an integer numbr, indeed, $ \sum_k^\infty (-1)^k(1+0)^k $ is divergence.